# bootstrap accordion default collapse all and working like flipkart refine search

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I am using bootstrap accrodion for refine search. I need some changes in the accordion.

I want open all accordion elements initial.

If click on the accordion element , the current element is closed.

Once again if I click on the element , the element is opened and remaining elements are closed.This is the default functionality of bootstrap. But I need, if I click on the element for open , remaining elements should not be effect like closed.

What I want exactly is , which item clicked the item only open or closed the same item. It should not effect on remaining elements.

just like flipkart refine search, it is available in the left side panel.I give the link.

https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Samsung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [accordion documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events) you can set:

- toggle to false for each *panel-collapse*
- show each *panel-collapse*
- on each hide/show accordion event you can toggle the class

The example:

```js
$('.panel-collapse').collapse({
    toggle: false
}).collapse('show');

$('#accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        $(e.target).prev('div').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-menu-up');
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life......
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                Collapsible Group Item #2  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, .....
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                Collapsible Group Item #3  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, .....
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working fine. This is what I want. Thanks a lot.